# Export Managed Metadata from List to CSV

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm trying to export an SPO list into CSV, which is working fine for Single line of text fields, however, when trying to export a managed metadata field, I'm getting the following appear in the CSV for the column:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

The script I am using is from this website http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/export-list-items-to-csv-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html.

How can I modify the script to show the value of the managed metadata field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. For anyone else looking:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue]$Value = $_["FieldName"]

$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Field Label" -value $Value.label
```